# workfront-api create users do not return anything

Tags: attask, workfront-api

good day, I can create a User by workfront-api, i try anyways to get informations from service but anysuccess from response.
Anyone already have this problem?

Comment: Can you post your api Call you are using to create the user?

Comment: Good morning Michael, thank you, this url https://cl02.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/user?name=user&username=user

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a user you need to pass the information using JSON formatting. This is because username is a keyword used for Authentication.

the correct method would look like this

```
?updates={"firstName":"Test","lastName":"User","username":"test@test.com","emailAddr":"test@test.com"}
```

If you do not use JSON the system will think you are trying to authenticate as the username.